# IHeadersDictionary returning null after mocking

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

I am trying to mock IHeadersDictionary and whenever I try to access it I returns Null.

```
public interface IRequestScopeContext
{
    IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; set; }
    ISessionInfo SessionInfo { get; set; }
    HttpContext HttpContextInfo { get; set; }
}

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Key", "Value"}
    } as IHeaderDictionary;

    var sessionInfo = new SessionInfo
    {
        AccountId = "AccountId",
        UserId = "UserId",
    };

    requestScopeContext = new Mock<IRequestScopeContext>();
    requestScopeContext.Setup(x => x.Headers).Returns(headers);
    requestScopeContext.Setup(x => x.SessionInfo).Returns(sessionInfo);

    serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
    serviceProvider.Setup(sp => sp.GetService(It.Is<Type>((Type t) => t.Name.Equals("IRequestScopeContext")))).Returns(requestScopeContext.Object);

    httpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    httpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.RequestServices).Returns(serviceProvider.Object);
}
```

I also tried using

```
requestScopeContext.Setup(x => x.Headers.Add( "Key", "Value"));
```

but whenever I access `requestScopeContext.Headers` it returns me null.

How should I mock this dictionary ?

My TestMethod is this

```
[Test]
public void SessionHelper_InvokeConstructor_Should_ReturnValidObject()
{
    var sessionHelper = new SessionHelper(httpContextAccessor.Object);

    Assert.IsNotNull(sessionHelper);
}
```

And this is the piece of code I am testing.

```
public SessionHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    IRequestScopeContext requestScopeContext = (IRequestScopeContext)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IRequestScopeContext));

    currentAccountId = requestScopeContext.SessionInfo?.AccountId;
    currentUserId = requestScopeContext.SessionInfo?.UserId;
    requestId = requestScopeContext.Headers?["key"];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Iurii Maksimov mentioned, your casting is incorrect - there is no direct cast between `Dictionary<string, string>` and `IHeaderDictionary`, use this instead:

```
var headers = new HeaderDictionary(new Dictionary<String, StringValues>
{
    { "Key", "Value"}
}) as IHeaderDictionary;
```

Comment: yes, I am passing requestScopeContext.Object to my constructor. In the constructor I am trying to access the headers.

Comment: I have edited my post, please look at the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to offer a slightly tidier way to achieve this, based on Alex Riabov's answer:

```
IHeaderDictionary headers = new HeaderDictionary()
{
    { "Header", "Value" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your casting work?

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Key", "Value"}
    } as IHeaderDictionary;
```

Here I tested Moq fast. Configuration is right.
[image]

Comment: Your headers object is of A type. my headers object is a Dictionary.

Comment: @Siddharth yes, I was about showing the right configuration to allocate problem with the object header. Good to find the problem.